# Use jQuery Media Plugin with audio/video stored in database

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using jQuery media plugin for making a media player. My media player should play audio/video. files stored in a sql server database that is retrieved by another aspx page with ContentType header equal to MIME Type.

so i can reach a stored media with "abc.aspx?id=123" Url.

the problem is jQuery media plugin is check file extension to play it, because my file extension is aspx it cannot understand the content of file.

is there any solution for this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Though pretty late to reply, and I hope you would have tailored some solution for it, Appending below solution for other reaching here for the same problem.

```
abc.aspx?id=123&ext=.wav
abc.aspx?id=123&ext=.mp3
abc.aspx?id=123&ext=.flv
```

will solve the problem. You can progamatically append the extention type based on the MIME type of file stored in DB or you can save extention of file while uploading it.